# Responsive Design: CSS Not loading on Iphone 5 Safari

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-safari, iphone-5

I'm searching for a reason and a hint why my website ([Link](https://app.voiceoffriends.com/places.php?cid=976)) is not shown correctly with responsive design (based on Twitter Bootstrap) on iPhone5  Safari Browser while it is completely working correctly on desktop using IE, Chrome or Safari. Also on HTC & Samsung Galaxy the website is working correctly.

By Googling I only could find 2 solutions which are 
A) cleaning the cache of the browser and 
B) using

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Both doesn't fix the problem. Also simulating the iPhone 5 Device in Google Developer Tool shows the website correctly while in reality the page does not show the CSS design.

Here the: 
[False Responsive Design Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GaIQ.jpg)

**Any idea what I need to look for as I'm running out of possible ideas.**

Comment: It appears fine in my iPhone 5s. Did you clear the history on your phone? It also happened to me last time and then I found that previous css file was already in my iPhone history and even after refreshing the old css file was loading instead of the new one.

Comment: Maihan, thanks for checking. I checked and I have an iPhone 5c and I could not find any reference to similar issue on this. Could I ask you to share a screenshot? I cleared the history and restarted the phone but still it's not working.

Comment: Here are the screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/nj3EN

Comment: Thanks Maihan. Based on the screenshot we moved away from the Iphone theory and discovered that there was simply a problem in one of the CSS files. We had a false symbol (?) in the file and this triggered that the full CSS was not loaded correctly. It seems though that all other devices were able to compensate the mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot we moved away from the Iphone theory and discovered that there was simply a problem in one of the CSS files. We had a false symbol (?) in the file and this triggered that the full CSS was not loaded correctly. It seems though that all other devices were able to compensate the mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Download bootstrap to your web server and include the path in the page, so don't have to rely on another source that could go down. This should fix your problem, if not, then just try Cordova. It is possible that your your phone is being blocked by the bootstrap site because the it is going over mobile network or something like that.

Source: Personal Experience

Regards,
PRO